# Good 3rd Party GridView with merge/overlay features

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-controls

Are there any datagridview controls from a 3rd party component companies, such as Telerik, that have a feature for merging cells or overlaying cells into one?

Answer (score 0):

[DevExpress XtraGrids](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/&ei=9ay-TdrBGdOftge_wojkBQ&usg=AFQjCNGfcEEgavsgUYozOMcoJ-OkDMcGmg&sig2=cXkKgMf6DmUs5--monyzig) does not allow cell merging along the columns. But it does allow cell merging along consecutive rows.

Do check the below link and see if this is what you're looking for.

[Cell Merging in DevExpress XtraGrid](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1461)

Answer (score 0):

Try Infragistics UltraWeb Grid...